# mincss right align navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm using [mincss](http://mincss.com/) and its navbar but I'm struggling to create a right-aligned link. The link is shown on the right side but its vertical position is not consistent.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mincss.com/entireframework.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav" tabindex="-1" onclick="this.focus()">
        <div class="container" style="overflow: hidden;margin-top: 0px;">
            <a class="pagename current" href="#">My Title Here</a>
            <a href="#">item</a>
            <a href="#">item</a>
            <a href="#"  style="float: right;">item</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn-close btn btn-sm">×</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ypwnsvm/)

As you can see, the last item on the right does not properly align with the two items on the left side.

This is because of the difference in text height of the title and the next elements. When an element is floated to the right, it seems to forget the vertical position it was in from what I gather.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: provide a jsfiddle to solve your problem

Comment: @Thinker okay, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the line height is off is because the unfloated elements follow the `line-height` from the larger text in the `.container`.

My personal approach is to set each link to float, then adjust the line height for all items - this avoids using some kind of "magic number" to adjust that one item.

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/7qu64ax6/

CSS:

```
.leftalign {
  float: left;
}

.rightalign {
  float: right;
}

.leftalign, .rightalign {
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <a class="pagename current leftalign" href="#">My Title Here</a>
    <a class="leftalign" href="#">item</a>
    <a class="leftalign" href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#" class="rightalign">item</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but you could just add:

```
.rightalign {
  float: right;
  padding-top:7px;
}
```